# C++11 lambda create destroy

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, lambda

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
   auto func_1 = [a] (int a) { return a > 1; }
   func_1();
}
```

`func_1` will again and again create and destroy ?

```
void forFunc()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
       auto func_2 = [a] (int a) { return a > 1; }
       func_2();
    }
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    forFunc();
}
```

`func_2` will again and again create and destroy ?

Comment: `a` isn't in scope to be captured in either of these. You are also failing to pass an argument to either `func_1` or `func_2`. Did you mean `[i] () { return i > 1; }` or `[] (int a) { return a > 1; }`? You are also ignoring the return values.

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is not just special for lambda objects but same for other objects with block scope too. For every iteration you'll get a brand-new object which gets created at the point of definition and destroyed at the end of the block.

[[stmt.iter]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#2)

(emphasis mine)

> The substatement in an [***iteration-statement***](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#nt:iteration-statement) implicitly **defines a block [scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope) which is entered and exited each time through the loop**.